# Increase value of cells until a threshold, then display remainder and thereafter text

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a row that begins with 50. As the row progresses from left to right, I want to increase this value by 50%. I have a threshold that is set at 200. The value cannot increase beyond this, but must show the remainder before it passes the threshold. After this, it should display the text "MAX".

To give a bit of context, I have a population of 200 people. Of this group, 50 contract a disease, which spreads throughout the population at a rate of increase of 50% of the currently infected population. Obviously you cannot infect more than 200 people as this is the threshold, and so the last cell before the first "MAX" should show the remaining number of people left to be infected, then all subsequent cells should show "MAX". e.g.

```
50,75,113,169,31,MAX,MAX,MAX,MAX etc
```

Where 31 is the remaining population to be infected (200-169) and `50+75+113+169+31 = 200`. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm confused by something: "50+75+113+169+31 = 200". In fact, 50+75+113+169+31 = 438.

Comment: Do you mean 169+31 = 200?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put A1 = 200, A2 = 50, put this formula to B2 and extend to C2, D2....

```
=IF(AND(A2>=$A$2, ISNUMBER(A2)),IF((1+0.5)*A2<$A$1,(1+0.5)*A2,$A$1-A2),"max")
```

Got exactly what you need

```
50  75  113 169 31  max max max max
```

Answer (score 0):

Put 50 in cell A1. Then put this formula in cell B1 and fill right:

```
=IF(SUM($A$1:A1)=200,"MAX",IF(SUM($A$1:A1)+A1*1.5>200,200-SUM($A$1:A1),A1*1.5))
```

Comment: Yeah, your formula will put 75 in both B1 and C1 and max the rest.

Comment: That seems to be the desired behaviour, since 50+75+75 = 200.

Comment: To me the desired behavior is `50,75,113,169,31,MAX,MAX,MAX,MAX ` and the comment `50+75+113+169+31 = 200` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

due to rounding I get a slightly different output with this:

```
=IF(OR(A1<INDEX(1:1,MAX(COLUMN()-2,1)),A1="Max"),"Max",ROUND(IF(A1*1.5>200,200-A1,A1*1.5),0))
```

Put 50 in A1 and this formula in B1 and copy over.

[image]